# Elementwise mean of numpy arrays from pandas dataframe cells

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a 2x1 pandas dataframe where the 2 cells contain numpy arrays:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a0 = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 2]])
>>> a1 = np.array([[3, 2], [1, 1]])
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[a0], [a1]])
```

I can compute the element-wise mean of the two arrays as follows:

```
>>> np.mean(df[0])
array([[ 2. ,  2. ],
       [ 1.5,  1.5]])
```

Now I want to consider the case where at least one of the arrays contains nan/s, e.g.

```
>>> a0 = np.array([[1, 2], [2, np.nan]])
>>> a1 = np.array([[3, 2], [1, 1]])
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[a0], [a1]])
```

The mean method used above gives

```
>>> np.mean(df[0])
array([[ 2. ,  2. ],
       [ 1.5,  nan]])
```

as expected. I want the nan/s to be ignored though. I would have expected the following to work

```
>>> np.nanmean(df[0])
array([[ -4.,  -4.],
       [ -3.,  nan]])
```

but it obviously doesn't.

So, my question: how can I compute element-wise means of numpy arrays which are contained in the cells of a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Two questions: You may not be mixing index 0 and column 0, right? Perhaps naming the dataframe columns could help. And, the expected result from `np.nanmean(df[0])` would be `array([[ 2. ,  2. ], [ 1.5,  1]])`?

Comment: (i) I get the same result if I use e.g. 'c' as column name. (ii) Yes, expected result is `np.array([[2., 2.], [1.5, 1.]])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand correctly, partly because I get confused with index 0 and column name 0... But here is an idea:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: a0 = np.array([[1, 2], [2, np.nan]])

In [4]: a1 = np.array([[3, 2], [1, 1]])

In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame([[a0], [a1]])

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
                          0
0  [[1.0, 2.0], [2.0, nan]]
1          [[3, 2], [1, 1]]

In [7]: df[0].as_matrix()
Out[7]: 
array([array([[  1.,   2.],
       [  2.,  nan]]),
       array([[3, 2],
       [1, 1]])], dtype=object)

In [8]: np.array( [ item for item in df[0].as_matrix() ] )
Out[8]: 
array([[[  1.,   2.],
        [  2.,  nan]],

       [[  3.,   2.],
        [  1.,   1.]]])

In [9]: np.nanmean( np.array( [ item for item in df[0].as_matrix() ]
   ...:  ), axis=0 )
Out[9]: 
array([[ 2. ,  2. ],
       [ 1.5,  1. ]])

In [10]: np.nanmean( np.array( [ item for item in df[0].as_matrix() 
    ...: ] ), axis=1 )
Out[10]: 
array([[ 1.5,  2. ],
       [ 2. ,  1.5]])

In [11]: np.nanmean( np.array( [ item for item in df[0].as_matrix() 
    ...: ] ), axis=2 )
Out[11]: 
array([[ 1.5,  2. ],
       [ 2.5,  1. ]])
```